# how to change device id (android id) programmatically

Tags: android

I'm looking for a way to change device id (android id) programmatically in eclipce. I tried this way but It did'nt work.

```
Secure.putString(getContentResolver(),Secure.ANDROID_ID,"new id");
```

what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your own custom ROM and have your app signed by the same signing key that signed the custom ROM's firmware. Or, you can root your device and install your app as a system app. Then, you can have a `<uses-permission>` element for `WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS`, and you can see whether your code will work.

Otherwise, you cannot modify those values. Quoting [the documentation for `Settings.Secure`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html):

> Secure system settings, containing system preferences that applications can read but are not allowed to write. These are for preferences that the user must explicitly modify through the system UI or specialized APIs for those values, not modified directly by applications.

Comment: how can i install my app as a system app? I mean that when the user installs my app in him device,  the app installs as a system app. is there any way?

Comment: @MostafaShakoori: "is there any way?" -- the device has to be rooted. Then there are some recipes for moving the app over to the system partition, though I do not know all of the details.