# How to change Android device's uuid?

Tags: android

I am testing my app's OAuth method and need to change my device's uuid number. I tried changing the Device ID through Device ID Changer and it was successful, however my uuid reminds the same when I call for it. I know doing a factory reset will change the uuid but that doesn't seem to be very efficient. Is there other ways to modify the device's uuid?

This is not the same as changing device id (android id) programmatically.

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/ Ask it here

Comment: @SiddharthVenu because it is really a development related issue and ordinary users have very little reason to change uuid (would log off all of their oauth accounts), so I think stackoverflow is more appropriate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change device id (android id) programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30832701/how-to-change-device-id-android-id-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, if you change the device ID and then do a hard restart (turn off and turn on the device) it should change the uuid. There could be ways to change uuid without the need of restarting. I am not aware of them.

Comment: I see. I only did a soft restart. Still would hope to do this without restarting the device.